# How do I get a endpoints and key for Microsoft Cognitive Services APIs?

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-cognitive-services

I have created Cognitivenik Cognitive Services. And trying to access this api via postman request. I am getting 404 resource not found response . What the wrong with URL?

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do with the Cognitive Service? There are many features and the endpoint is different based on what you are doing. For example, if I wanted to get a Sentiment of a sentence, it would be in your case  https://cognitivenik.congnitiveservices.azure.com/text/analytics/v2.1/sentiment

More examples: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you know the service you need, you need to find the API url for it. In this example I will use the [TextAnalytics Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/text-analytics/) for sentiment analysis.

The url to call this endpoint for you would be

```
https://cognitivenik.congnitiveservices.azure.com/text/analytics/v2.1/sentiment
```

Your headers look good so just updating the API Url, it should work for you.